# how to use "kubectl apply -f <file.yaml> --force=true" making an impact over a deployed container EXEC console?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to redeploy the exact same existing image, but after changing a secret in the Azure Vault.  Since it is the same image that's why `kubectl apply` doesn't deploy it. I tried to make the deploy happen by adding a `--force=true` option. Now the deploy took place and the new secret value is visible in the dashboard config map, but not in the API container `kubectl exec` console prompt in the environment.

Below is one of the 3 deploy manifest (YAML file) for the service:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tube-api-deployment
  namespace: tube
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tube-api-app
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tube-api-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tube-api
        image: ReplaceImageName
        ports:
        - name: tube-api
          containerPort: 80
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: tube-config-map
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: ReplaceRegistrySecret
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-service
  namespace: tube
spec:
  ports:
   - name: api-k8s-port
     protocol: TCP
     port: 8082
     targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: tube-api-app
```

Comment: How does the secret get into the container?  What command are you trying to run to inspect it?

Comment: Hello, is this Azure Vault secret in the `Configmap` `tube-config-map` or is it embeeded in the image? environment variables from `Configmaps` are not subject to change unless the `Pod` is restarted. Have you restarted your `Pods`?

Comment: @DavidMaze the secret gets into container during image deploy process. in this case since the image is the same only a secret is altered, so I tried "kubectl apply" with --force=true option but the deploy failed as the secret change is not reflected on api container's exec console (accessed via dashboard). However, ConfigMap (accessed via dashboard) shows the secret change. Thanks.

Comment: @DawidKruk yes, it is Azure Vault secret in the Configmap tube-config-map. it's not embedded in the image. No I have not restarted the pods. Let me restart pods and confirm. Thanks.

Comment: @DawidKruk pod restarting picks up the change but is there any way to do it by using 'kubectl apply" or by modifying the manifest files without the restart?

Comment: @MCC21 Apologies for such late reply, missed your comment. What I think you mean by your comment is there any way to update the `Configmap` value without a restart of a `Pod`. It's possible through mounting a `Configmap` as a `Volume` (which will be updated eventually). Please take a look here for more reference:  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#using-configmaps-as-files-from-a-pod

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not happening because when we update a ConfigMap, the files in all the volumes referencing it are updated. It’s then up to the pod container process to detect that they’ve been changed and reload them. Currently, there is no built-in way to signal an application when a new version of a ConfigMap is deployed. It is up to the application (or some helper script) to look for the config files to change and reload them.